# Saving a Python dictionary in external file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on a code that is essentially a super basic AI system (basically a simple Python version of Cleverbot).

As part of the code, I've got a starting dictionary with a couple keys that have lists as the values. As the file runs, the dictionary is modified - keys are created and items are added to the associated lists.

So what I want to do is have the dictionary saved as an external file in the same file folder, so that the program doesn't have to "re-learn" the data each time I start the file. So it will load it at the start of running the file, and at the end it will save the new dictionary in the external file. How can I do this?

Do I have to do this using JSON, and if so, how do I do it? Can I do it using the built-in json module, or do I need to download JSON? I tried to look up how to use it but couldn't really find any good explanations.

I have my main file saved in C:/Users/Alex/Dropbox/Coding/AI-Chat/AI-Chat.py

The phraselist is saved in C:/Users/Alex/Dropbox/Coding/AI-Chat/phraselist.py

I'm running Python 2.7 through Canopy.

When I run the code, this is the output:

```
In [1]: %run "C:\Users\Alex\Dropbox\Coding\AI-Chat.py"
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Dropbox\Coding\phraselist.py", line 2
    S'How are you?'
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

EDIT: I got it now. I had to specify the sys.path to import phrase frome phraselist.py

Here's the full code I have:

```
############################################
################ HELPER CODE ###############
############################################
import sys
import random
import json
sys.path = ['C:\\Users\\Alex\\Dropbox\\Coding\\AI-Chat'] #needed to specify path
from phraselist import phrase



def chooseResponse(prev,resp):
    '''Chooses a response from previously learned responses in phrase[resp]    
    resp: str
    returns str'''
    if len(phrase[resp])==0: #if no known responses, randomly choose new phrase
        key=random.choice(phrase.keys())
        keyPhrase=phrase[key]
        while len(keyPhrase)==0:
            key=random.choice(phrase.keys())
            keyPhrase=phrase[key]
        else:
            return random.choice(keyPhrase)
    else:
        return random.choice(phrase[resp])

def learnPhrase(prev, resp):
    '''prev is previous computer phrase, resp is human response
    learns that resp is good response to prev
    learns that resp is a possible computer phrase, with no known responses

    returns None
    '''
    #learn resp is good response to prev
    if prev not in phrase.keys():
        phrase[prev]=[]
        phrase[prev].append(resp)
    else:
        phrase[prev].append(resp) #repeat entries to weight good responses

    #learn resp is computer phrase
    if resp not in phrase.keys():
        phrase[resp]=[]

############################################
############## END HELPER CODE #############
############################################

def chat():
    '''runs a chat with Alan'''
    keys = phrase.keys()
    vals = phrase.values()

    print("My name is Alan.")
    print("I am an Artifical Intelligence Machine.")
    print("As realistic as my responses may seem, you are talking to a machine.")
    print("I learn from my conversations, so I get better every time.")
    print("Please forgive any incorrect punctuation, spelling, and grammar.")
    print("If you want to quit, please type 'QUIT' as your response.")
    resp = raw_input("Hello! ")

    prev = "Hello!"

    while resp != "QUIT":
        learnPhrase(prev,resp)
        prev = chooseResponse(prev,resp)
        resp = raw_input(prev+' ')
    else:
        with open('phraselist.py','w') as f:
            f.write('phrase = '+json.dumps(phrase))
        print("Goodbye!")

chat()
```

And phraselist.py looks like:

```
phrase = {
    'Hello!':['Hi!'],
    'How are you?':['Not too bad.'],
    'What is your name?':['Alex'],
}
```

Comment: Why not write to another Python file so that you can simply import as a dictionary?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pickle`  module for that. 
This module have two methods,

1. **Pickling(dump)**: Convert Python objects into string representation.
2. **Unpickling(load)**: Retrieving original objects from stored string representstion.

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html
code:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> with open("test.txt", "wb") as fp:   #Pickling
...   pickle.dump(l, fp)
... 
>>> with open("test.txt", "rb") as fp:   # Unpickling
...   b = pickle.load(fp)
... 
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Following is sample code for our problem:

1. Define phrase file name and use same file name during create/update phrase data and also during get phrase data.
2. Use exception handling during get phrase data i.e. check if file is present or not on disk by `os.path.isfile(file_path)` method.
3. As use `dump` and `load` pickle methods to set and get phrase.

code:

```
import os
import pickle
file_path = "/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/phrase.json"

def setPhrase():
    phrase = {
        'Hello!':['Hi!'],
        'How are you?':['Not too bad.'],
        'What is your name?':['Alex'],
    }
    with open(file_path, "wb") as fp:
        pickle.dump(phrase, fp)

    return 

def getPhrase(): 
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, "rb") as fp: 
            phrase = pickle.load(fp)
    else:
        phrase = {}

    return phrase

if __name__=="__main__":
    setPhrase()

    #- Get values.
    phrase = getPhrase()
    print "phrase:", phrase
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 22.py
phrase: {'How are you?': ['Not too bad.'], 'What is your name?': ['Alex'], 'Hello!': ['Hi!']}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can dump it in json (built into python so you don't need to install it)

```
import json 
json.dump(your_dictionary, open('file_name.json', 'wb'))
```

You can use pickle but the file will not be human readable. Pickling is useful when you need to store python (or custom) objects.

Comment: actually, hm it would have to be modified slightly.  For your answer you'd have to dump it and load it each time.  For mine you'd have to load the module and then output
'phrase = ' +json.dumps(phrase) to the file

Comment: This is essentially like pickling but you actually can make sense of the output

Comment: _pickle_ uses less storage space; and _cPickle_ is much faster than _pickle_

Answer (score 0):

If you have it stored in a file in the same directory, you could do:

phraselist.py

```
phrase = {'Hello!':['Hi!'],'How are you?':['Not too bad.'],
      'What is your name?':['Alex']
     }
```

and in your other file do:

```
from phraselist import phrase
```

then you can reference phrase as you wish.  If you actually want to modify the module, you could keep track of the dict throughout your program and just before you exit, save it back to the python file with its new contents. There might be a more elegant way to do this, but...it should work.

right before you exit:

```
with open('phraselist.py', 'w') as f:
   f.write('phrase = '+ json.dumps(phrase))
```

interpreter output:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from phraselist import phrase
>>> phrase
{'How are you?': ['Not too bad.'], 'What is your name?': ['Alex'], 'Hello!': ['Hi!']}
>>> phrase['Goodbye'] = ['See you later']
>>> phrase
{'How are you?': ['Not too bad.'], 'What is your name?': ['Alex'], 'Goodbye': ['See you later'], 'Hello!': ['Hi!']}
>>> import json
>>> with open('phraselist.py', 'w') as f:
...   f.write('phrase = ' + json.dumps(phrase))
...
>>>
>>> exit()
XXX@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from phraselist import phrase
>>> phrase
{'How are you?': ['Not too bad.'], 'What is your name?': ['Alex'], 'Goodbye': ['See you later'], 'Hello!': ['Hi!']}
>>>
```

YOUR CODE:

phraselist.py:

```
phrase = {'Hello!':['Hi!'],'How are you?':['Not too bad.'],'What is your name?':['Alex']}
```

output from running

```
XXXX@ubuntu:~$ python AI-Chat.py
My name is Alan.
I am an Artifical Intelligence Machine.
As realistic as my responses may seem, you are talking to a machine.
I learn from my conversations, so I get better every time.
Please forgive any incorrect punctuation, spelling, and grammar.
If you want to quit, please type 'QUIT' as your response.
Hello! hey
Alex what's up?
Not too bad. cool
cool what do you do?
Not too bad. ...okay
what's up? not much, you?
what do you do? I'm a software engineer, what about you?
hey ...hey
not much, you? i'm going to stop now
Alex Goodbye!
i'm going to stop now sigh...
hey QUIT
Goodbye!

XXX@ubuntu:$vi phraselist.py
phrase = {"...okay": [], "not much, you?": ["i'm going to stop now"], "Alex": ["what's up?", "Goodbye!"], "i'm going to stop now": ["sigh..."], "What is your name?": ["Alex"], "Not too bad.": ["cool",     "...okay"], "hey": ["...hey"], "...hey": [], "How are you?": ["Not too bad."], "sigh...": [], "what do you do?": ["I'm a software engineer, what about you?"], "what's up?": ["not much, you?"], "Goodb    ye!": [], "Hello!": ["Hi!", "hey"], "I'm a software engineer, what about you?": [], "cool": ["what do you do?"]}
```

the one modification I made in AI-Chat.py:

```
while resp != "QUIT":
    learnPhrase(prev,resp)
    prev = chooseResponse(prev,resp)
    resp = raw_input(prev+' ')
else:
    with open('phraselist.py','w') as f:
        f.write('phrase = '+json.dumps(phrase))
    print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I should note that I'm running Python 2.7 through Canopy (because I'm doing a programming class and that's what they use - I've only been coding for a couple weeks).
Suggestions?

Comment: what error output are you seeing?  I'm going to edit my post with my output from the interpeter

Comment: Okay, here's what I'm getting now. When I run the code, it says

%run "C:\Users\Alex\Dropbox\Coding\AI-Chat.py"
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Dropbox\Coding\phraselist.py", line 2
    S'How are you?'
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


I double checked both my files, and I don't see any part where it has S'How are you?'

Why does Python think there is an error?

I editted my original post to include my full code.

Comment: get rid of any whitespace you have in phraselist.py...it should be only one line.  That might fix your problem

Comment: your code seems to work for me...(sorta, lol) i'm going to update my answer with the output that I get from running the code you pasted (with one small modification)

Comment: Hm. I'm still getting the same thing. I modified phraselist.py to contain only one entry phrase={'Hello!':['Hi.'],} but I'm still getting the exact same Syntax Error -- S'How are you?' SyntaxError: invalid syntax, when 'How' doesn't even appear in either file. Ever.
I tried restarting Canopy and reloading the files too. Weird. Maybe I'll try one of the other responses and see if they work better for me.

And yeah, it's really bad. It hardly counts as an AI, it's more that it just copies what you say. But it's still kinda fun, and it's good practice for me.

Comment: If you're getting that error something must be up...I'm using exactly the code you gave me and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using cPickles, it can store any python structure to a file

```
import cPickles as p
p.dump([Your Data], [Your File])
```

No matter it's a list, set, dictionary or what else.