# Variable that increments even if program closes

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, counter

I'm making a program that remotely records video on a camera from a button press and will save the video file externally after I'm done recording.

I need to know the name of the video file to access it, and each time the video saves, the number in the file gets incremented.

E.g. first video that saves is mov_0001, then the next time I save a new video it's mov_0002

Is there a way to make a variable to increment and it saves at whatever the last value was, so even if I close the program and open it again it'll be what it was the previous time the program ran?

Comment: The answer to the only question in this post is **Yes**.   Now what?  To get high quality answers it is important to provide [a high quality question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use file method to store next which counter is used.**

Use normal text file or Pickle file or Json file to store  counter of video file name.

**Demo:**

Pickling - How to Store value in pickle file.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> store_file = "file_counter.txt"
>>> counter = 10
>>> fp = open(store_file, "w")
>>> pickle.dump(counter, fp)
>>> fp.close()
```

Unpickling- How to extract value from pickle file.

```
>>> fp_r = open(store_file, "r")
>>> old_counter = pickle.load(fp_r)
>>> old_counter
10
>>>
```

**Note:** Use default value to 1 if not.

[Documentation of Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html)

[Demo of Pickling and Unpickling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572420/saving-a-python-dictionary-in-external-file/28572489#28572489)

---

**Find file name which have greater counter in his file name.**

1. Get video file list from location where you store video files by using `os.lidtdir("$Vedio_location_path$")`
2. Now sort list of files list from point 1 by using `list sort` method or `sorted` function.
3. Get last file name from a vedio list.
4. As you names have specific pattern, so spilt according to pattern and get last counter value which you used.
5. Increment counter by one and use to store next video file.

**Demo:**

```
>>> video_files = ["mov_0001", "mov_0002", "mov_0005", "mov_0003"]
>>> video_files.sort()
>>> video_files
['mov_0001', 'mov_0002', 'mov_0003', 'mov_0005']
>>> last_file = video_files[-1]
>>> counter = int(last_file.split("_")[1])
>>> counter
5
```

**Note:**

1. Do necessary exception handling.
2. Use default value to 1 then there is no video file present in your store location.
3. You can also modify above algorithm to get counter if any file is deleted.

E.g

i. Suppose there are `["mov_0001", "mov_0002", "mov_0003", "mov_0004"]` files.

ii. now we deleted `mov_0003` file, so list is `["mov_0001", "mov_0002",  "mov_0004"]`

iii. According to above algorithm used counter value will be `4`, but u can modify algorithm to get deleted file counter.

---